# Como puedo hacer una validación de que si esta subiendo un archivo repetido o bien insertando datos duplicados c#

Tags: excel, insert, datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo la cual deseo que me valide si la persona esta importando un archivo excel y me diga si existe en la base de datos y no lo importe , si no existe los datos que los inserte , gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Las imagenes de codigo no suelen ser bien recibidas, es mejor que copies y pegues asi podemos hacer lo mismo para depurar, aparte te recomiendo que leas el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.